# xe:dialog does not show view data

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have an xe:dialog control on my xpage, with a view contol as a sort of picklist. The view shows entries of the current db. It's in a custom control, which is embedded in

A) an xpage with data of the current database,

B) an xpage with 2 data sources, doc1 is from a different db, doc2 is from the current db.

When I open (show) the dialog in case B), the view is always empty. The xpage B) is opened from a view of the different db.

the dialog code:

```
<xe:dialog id="diaSnippet" title="Textbaustein auswählen">
    <xp:panel>
        <xe:dialogContent id="dialogContent1">
            <xp:panel>
                <xp:inputText id="viwStartkey1"
                    value="#{viewScope.viwStartkey}">
                </xp:inputText>

                <xp:button iconAlt="Starts with" icon="/Search" id="bviwStartkey">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="viwOrgDB1">
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:button>
                <xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viwOrgDB1" var="kbEntry">
                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next"
                            xp:key="headerPager" id="pager2">
                        </xp:pager>
                    </xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:this.data>
                        <xp:dominoView var="view1"
                            startKeys="#{javascript:if (hasContent(viewScope.viwStartkey)) viewScope.viwStartkey}"
                            keys="#{javascript:viewScope.UpdateField}" keysExactMatch="true"
                            viewName="lookupSnippet" databaseName="xpages\chhp1017.nsf">
                        </xp:dominoView>
                    </xp:this.data>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="ID" id="viewColumn1"
                        displayAs="link" openDocAsReadonly="true">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Kurzbez."
                            id="viewColumnHeader1">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                            refreshMode="complete">
                            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var mySnippet = kbEntry.getColumnValue("Snippet");
    fback.replaceItemValue(viewScope.UpdateField,mySnippet)
    getComponent("diaSnippet").hide(viewScope.UpdateField + "1");
                        </xp:eventHandler>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Snippet" id="viewColumn2">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Textbaustein"
                            id="viewColumnHeader2">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>
                    <xp:viewColumn columnName="Comment" id="viewColumn3">
                        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Kommentar"
                            id="viewColumnHeader3">
                        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
                    </xp:viewColumn>

                </xp:viewPanel>
            </xp:panel>
        </xe:dialogContent>
        <xe:dialogButtonBar id="dialogButtonBar1">
            <xp:panel>
                <xp:button id="button3" value="OK">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="complete">
                        <xp:this.action>

                            <xp:actionGroup>




                                <xp:executeScript>
                                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("diaSnippet").hide()}]]></xp:this.script>
                                </xp:executeScript>
                            </xp:actionGroup>
                        </xp:this.action>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:button>
            </xp:panel>
        </xe:dialogButtonBar>
    </xp:panel>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onHide" submit="true"
        refreshMode="norefresh">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xe:dialog>
```

I tried a few things with the data source of the dominoView, current db, chosen db like in my code above, computed db path, but all with the same result.

Looks for me as if the dialog only works when "everything" is from the current db.

Thanks in advance, Uwe

Comment: If this is not a typo, `databaseName="xpages\chhp1017.nsf"` should be `databaseName="xpages\\chhp1017.nsf"` or `databaseName="xpages/chhp1017.nsf"`.

Comment: I did not type it in, I chose - just for this the example (so that one can see a data source here) it in the properties interface, And it worked with the version A), single data source = current db. The effect stays the same if I change it to "/". I think you only have to "mask" the "\", using "\\", if you do it in a computed js formula.

Comment: Can you add a computed field to the dialog box to see the value of the viewScope variable "UpdateField" and make sure, that is it not empty and actually contains a key value that is in the view? Also, could you please post the XML markup for the button / link that opens the dialog?

Comment: Daniel, the dialog is in one custom control, which is embedded in different xpages. The difference are the data sources of the xpages. But I already printed the sessionScope var "UpdateField" on the server console, it shows, as expected, the same in both cases.
I think the problem (even a bug?) is the data source: Looks as if a dialog can only keep data of the database it belongs to. A collegue told me he had quite a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's of any interest ....:

We found the reason: The data definition of the view was missing the

```
ignoreRequestParams="true"
```

that does the trick.